# When ?id= string contains "&" symbol, Request.QueryString[id] doesn't return entire string

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

Does anyone know how to get the entire string?

Example:

```
var result = Request.QueryString[id];
```

returns "Jack" instead of "Jack & Jill" for the URL "http://website.com/test.html?=Jack&Jill

Comment: Try using `Jack%26Jill` `%26` will be decoded to `&`

Answer (score 3):

**`&`** is a special character used to seperate paramaeters being passed. You need to encode your Url using ASP.NET provided functions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in reading the parameter, but in constructing it. You have to change your link, or the code that creates the link.

You have to use URL <strike>escaping</strike> [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

http://website.com/test.html?=Jack%26Jill

URL encoding is supported in .NET (`HttpUtility`) and JS (global functions) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()` when assigning the url to `id`